# When is a question not a question?

Tags: support

I tried to ask a question:

> Can we say 'you think therefore you are?'

http://www.britannica.com/topic/cogito-ergo-sum

but I got this:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

But my homepage says I haven't asked any questions!

Comment: Maybe it's about questions you've asked on other SEs? The network is all running on the same software

Comment: well my other sites aren't doing it

Comment: With respect to the prospective new question: I think it misses the entire point of Descartes' famous statement. *Cogito ergo sum* works precisely *because* I have the subjective *experience* of thinking; therefore there must be, t least, some "I" having that experience, doing that thinking. So I know, at a minimum, with absolute confidence, that I exist. But that confidence does t extend any further than that (at least not as a consequence of this argument). I have no way of knowing if "you" are real, and certainly no way of knowing "you" are thinking. You might be a hallucination.

Comment: In other words, no, the argument does not and can not extend to "*You think, therefore you are*", and even suggesting that indicates a misapprehension of the fundamental argument.

Comment: @DanBron; so i can completely ignore your argument then?

Comment: @jon By labeling it "*my* argument", you've already presupposed my independent existence, completely regardless of the argument's content. So no, you cannot. And, in case it hasn't occurred to you: saying "*argument X doesn't support conclusion Y*" does not mean "*conclusion Y is false*"; it may very well be, but it's equally possible that there exist *other, different* arguments which *do* support conclusion Y. So instead of trying to forcefully misapply Descartes' *cogito ergo sum*, maybe you should ask what noted philosophical arguments *do* support the conclusion others exist?

Answer (score 2):

Your questions were deleted.

The text of one is as follows:

> How many women does it take to change a light-bulb?
>
> I guess one is the correct answer, but jokes are supposed to be funny.

And the other was:

> In movies, the good guys always take a set-back before coming out on top. I have invented the phrase 'what goes down must come up'.
>
> Are there other instances of this idea, and more particularly, is there any scientific phenomena that exhibits this truism? (I have a buoy submerged in water).

I deleted the first one. The community closed and deleted the second one. In the comments about the second one where the user base interacted with you, you claimed to be someone who you don't appear to be.

You might want to look through the help center to better understand the intended scope of this SE.